# How come Spring Data Rest only allows updates from the owner side of ManyToOne/ManyToMany?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I downloaded a sample project from here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

I then ran it and did some test REST calls. As far as I can tell you can only update association from the owner side using SDR. What I mean is

```
public class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
    private Library library;
}
```

and

```
public class Library {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

You can't actually make post/put calls to /libraries/1/books. Server return 204 but no effect on the db whatsoever.

You can however, make post/put calls to /books/1/library and everything works as intended including keeping the other entity in sync.

Is this normal? It's the same behaviour for @ManyToMany as well. Is there a way to allow for updates from both sides? If I write my own API I can certainly make this the case. Why does SDR not do this?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this normal?

In a sense, yes. That's exactly how pure JPA would behave when you added a `Book` to the collection of `Library.books` with your current mapping - it would make no changes whatsoever.

My guess is that Spring Data Rest doesn't know (or care) which side of the association is the owner side, and just doesn't go the extra mile to make sure updating the inverse side works as well.

> Is there a way to allow for updates from both sides?

A workaround *could be* to simply pretend both sides of the associations were the owning side, i.e.:

```
public class Library {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
    private List<Book> books;
}
```

Be advised that this makes Hibernate treat `Library.books` and `Book.library` as two completely separate associations. In some corner cases, your entities may not behave the way you would expect. You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

Updating bidirectional relations from both sides is very tricky and will potentially cause side effects considering Springs endpoint authorization or Spring Data RESTs `BeforeLinkSaveEvent` and `AfterLinkSaveEvent` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events).

There has to be a strict parent child relation. I don't think that you can configure the desired behaviour.